# How to floor or ceil a fixed point number?

Tags: solidity, math, fixed-point

Say I have a signed 64.64 fixed point number `18444899399302180000` or `0.9999` in floating point notation. How can I define a `floor` and `ceil` function that floors or ceils an `int128` signed 64.64 fixed point number?

```
function floor(int128) returns(int128);
function ceil(int128) returns(int128);

floor(18444899399302180000) == 0 // floor(0.9999) == 0
floor(-18444899399302180000) == 0 // floor(-0.9999) == -1

ceil(18444899399302180000) == 18446744073709551616 // ceil(0.9999) == 1
ceil(-18444899399302180000) == 0 // ceil(-0.9999) == 0
```

Btw I'm using [ABDKMath64x64](https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol) for working with signed 64.64 fixed point numbers.

Comment: If you were using [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math) instead, you would get [floor](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math/blob/86c068e21f9ba229025a77b951bd3c4c4cf103da/contracts/PRBMathUD60x18.sol#L137-L150) and [ceil](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math/blob/86c068e21f9ba229025a77b951bd3c4c4cf103da/contracts/PRBMathUD60x18.sol#L43-L67) function by default.

Comment: Sorry for the shameless plug but PRBMath is quickly [becoming](https://twitter.com/boredGenius/status/1426027290807259142) the industry's favorite math library. It's faster, more practical and more intuitive than ABDK.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg great suggestion, I'm loving it so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to implement both `floor` and `ceil` as follows. The `ABDKMath64x64.toInt` function essentially floors the signed fixed point number to a signed integer, hence the following would hold true:

- `toInt(-18444899399302180000) == -1` i.e. floor(-0.9999) == -1
- `toInt(0) == 0` i.e.  floor(0) == 0
- `toInt(18444899399302180000) == 0` i.e. floor(0.9999) == 0
- `toInt(18446744073709551616) == 1` i.e. floor(1) == 1
- `toInt(-18446744073709551616) == -1` i.e. floor(-1) == -1

so all that is required is to then just cast the resulting integer result back to a signed fixed point number.

For `ceil` I first check if the signed fixed point number is a whole number integer by %(mod) by 1(unity), if it is then I simply return the number since the ceil of a whole number is that number. Else I take the fixed point number into the real number range above it's current real number range and then floor it, so for example if the number is `0.9999` I take it into the range of it's ceil i.e. [1, 2) by adding unity which makes it 1.9999, then flooring it gives us the ceil i.e. 1 in this case. hence the following holds true:

- `ceil(-18444899399302180000) == 0` i.e. ceil(-0.9999) == 0
- `ceil(0) == 0` i.e.  ceil(0) == 0
- `ceil(18444899399302180000) == 0` i.e. ceil(0.9999) == 1
- `ceil(18446744073709551616) == 1` i.e. ceil(1) == 1
- `ceil(-18446744073709551616) == -1` i.e. ceil(-1) == -1

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import { ABDKMath64x64 } from "./ABDKMath64x64.sol";

contract FloorCeil {

    int128 constant unity = 18446744073709551616;

    function floor(int128 fp) public pure returns(int128) {
        return ABDKMath64x64.fromInt(int256(ABDKMath64x64.toInt(fp)));
    }

    function ceil(int128 fp) public pure returns(int128) {
        if (fp == 0 || fp%unity == 0) {
            return fp;
        }
        return floor(ABDKMath64x64.fromInt(int256(ABDKMath64x64.toInt(ABDKMath64x64.add(fp, unity)))));
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an collision that I cannot yet explain 4097 for Q64.64 evaluates to 2 values: 75576310469988024582144, 75576310469988032970752, hence floor(75576310469988024582144) == 75557863725914323419136 which does not equal to floor(75576310469988032970752) == 75576310469988032970752

Comment: It's probably got something to do with a round error since 75576310469988024582144.toInt() == 4096 and 75576310469988032970752.toInt() == 4097